# Unable to unset the linux environment variable

Tags: linux, unset

Unable to unset the linux environment variable FLEXLM_DIAGNOSTICS

```
{goudarsh:tst_rep/}@vilc1199:/<8>ndm> echo $FLEXLM_DIAGNOSTICS
5
{goudarsh:tst_rep/}@vilc1199:/<8>ndm> unset FLEXLM_DIAGNOSTICS
{goudarsh:tst_rep/}@vilc1199:/<8>ndm> env |grep FLEX
FLEXLM_DIAGNOSTICS=5
```

can some give me other tricks to sovle this issue?

Comment: Is this really the full sequence of commands? `unset` will empty the variable from the current environment, but it's not for you so I suspect something else it up. Where is `FLEXLM_DIAGNOSTICS` being defined?

Comment: @Skrat yes this is sequence of commands and yesterday i had did executed this `setenv FLEXLM_DIAGNOSTICS 5` and i want to remove this value/variable but unset does not work for me

Comment: I can't test `setenv` as I don't use a `(t)csh` shell, but I think `unsetenv` is what you're looking for in this case, not `unset`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I was using `tcsh` shell, the command I should be using for is `unsetenv` to unset the variable.

Thanks to @Skrat.

Comment: @Skrat in the next 18hours i will mark it as the answer as stack overflow is not allowing